# Consulta SQL para comparar IDs en tres tablas

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Tengo una pequeña base de datos de prueba con **tres tablas**.

Básicamente son datos de profesores:

- La tabla **field_title** trae los nombres de los profesores
- La tabla **field_body** trae una descripción de su experiencia laboral
- La tabla **field_images** trae imágenes como títulos universitarios, por ej.

Todas tienen un campo como identificador en común el cual es **pages_id**.

Estas son las tablas:

**field_title**

```
pages_id      data
------------------------------
1060          Juan Carlos
1062          Ana Maria
1063          Jose Eduardo
1064          Juan Camilo
1068          Mario Andres
```

**field_body**

```
pages_id      data
------------------------------
1060          So, Jonathan, how was the pull-out? You act like y...
1062          Seitan art party dolore farm-to-table, slow-carb n...
1063          Yard maroon hulk cable wench tack furl bilge rat c...
1064          Está la cosa muy malar jarl aute incididunt. Tempo...
1068          No! Hoc non credant? Gus habet cameras ubique plac...
```

**field_images**

```
pages_id      data
------------------------------
1060          prfilepicture.png
1062          cierreimg.png
1062          enero.png
1063          boletin.png
1064          fondoblanco.png
1068          hv-44.png
1068          image.png
1068          profile.png
1068          otros.png
```

---

Lo que quiero hacer es traer con una consulta estos datos por registro: el nombre del profe, su biografía y su(s) imágen(es).

Esto es lo que intenté, para que trajera el primer resultado por ejemplo.

```
SELECT * FROM field_title, field_body, field_images
WHERE pages_id = '1060';
```

Luego me dí cuenta que puedo usar INNER JOIN en múltiples tablas, haciendo esto:

```
SELECT * FROM field_title, field_body, field_images
JOIN data ON ALL TABLES
WHERE pages_id = '1060';
```

Pero no entiendo muy bien cómo funciona.

El resultado esperado sería algo así como esto, en el primer caso:

```
Juan Carlos
So, Jonathan, how was the pull-out? You act like y...
prfilepicture.png
```

Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: `JOIN data`?, pero `data` no es una tabla..de todas formas, esto es hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con cada tabla que tienes

Comment: ademas de lo que te comentan, si tenes muchas imagenes por persona vas a ver el mismo registro varias veces.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @Lamak, data es un campo en cada una de las tres tablas. No soy muy bueno en SQL, lamento si cometo alguna falla

Comment: @gbianchi hola, gracias por comentar. En realidad lo de las imágenes no me preocupa si se repite, en realidad el código es mucho más largo y sólo tomaría en cuenta el primer registro de cada entrada o ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ACTUALIZADO:**

Si tenemos un campo fecha en field_images y queremos quedarnos con la primera (la más antigua), se podría adaptar la SQL a:

```
SELECT ft.pages_id, ft.data as autor, fb.data as body, fi.data as imagen
FROM 
field_title ft JOIN field_body fb on ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id
JOIN field_images fi on fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
where ft.pages_id = 1068 
and fi.fecha_insertado = (select min(fi2.fecha_insertado) from field_images fi2 where fi2.pages_id = ft.pages_id );
```

RESPUESTA ORIGINAL:

Yo haría 2 inner joins "típicos" entre las 3 tablas, uno encadenado con el otro:

```
SELECT ft.pages_id, ft.data as autor, fb.data as body, fi.data as imagen
FROM 
field_title ft JOIN field_body fb on ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id
JOIN field_images fi on fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
where ft.pages_id = 1068;
```

El "problema" es que el autor y el body se van a repetir por cada imagen de la misma página, pero la agrupación en ese caso la haría (si fuera encesario) en la parte del programa principal (fuera del SQL).

La salida de la query sería algo como:

```
pages_id    autor   body    imagen  
1068    Mario Andrés    No! Hoc non credant? Gus habet cameras ubique plac...   otros.png   
1068    Mario Andrés    No! Hoc non credant? Gus habet cameras ubique plac...   profile.png 
1068    Mario Andrés    No! Hoc non credant? Gus habet cameras ubique plac...   image.png   
1068    Mario Andrés    No! Hoc non credant? Gus habet cameras ubique plac...   hv-44.png
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo y su respuesta, funciona como lo necesitaba. Sobre las imágenes que se repiten, yo en esa tabla tengo un campo fecha_insertado, sé que la primera imagen en ser subida es la que necesito. Podría esta información servirme de algo? Haciendo un limit por ejemplo?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, aunque la SQL ha fallado en tu página, por que el campo no existe, no se si es que no está actualizado el modelo, en todo caso, si la columna se llama diferente, se adaptaría fácil

Comment: Gracias! El error era mío en el nombre del campo, ya lo corregí con ayuda de tu respuesta

Comment: Hola de nuevo, acabo de crear una pregunta con base a tu código, por si gustas echarle un vistazo! :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328988/