# Consulta en SQL que devuelva últimos registros según ID

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Esta pregunta se basa en [esta respuesta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/328262/109595)

---

Gracias al usuario [@Roberto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/155387/), logré modificar el siguiente código que hace una consulta anidada a cuatro tablas en una base de datos:

```
SELECT ft.pages_id, 
       ft.data AS titulo, 
       fb.data AS body, 
       fi.data AS imagen, 
       pg.name AS link 
FROM   field_title ft 
       JOIN field_body fb 
         ON ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id 
       JOIN field_images fi 
         ON fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
       JOIN pages pg 
         ON pg.id = pg.id 
WHERE  ( ft.pages_id = 1062 ) 
       AND ( pg.id = 1062 ) 
       AND ( fi.created = (SELECT Min(fi2.created) 
                           FROM   field_images fi2 
                           WHERE  fi2.pages_id = ft.pages_id) );
```

Esto lo que hace es traer los registros correspondientes a un ID (1062 en este caso). Funciona bien.

Lo que estoy haciendo ahora es pasar esos registros a un elemento *card* de Bootstrap, me dí cuenta que con 1 solo *template* de estas *cards*, si la consulta SQL trae dos filas (`row`) o más, automáticamente se crean los *templates* de dicha *card*, eso está genial.

Pensando en eso, lo que deseo es que la consulta SQL me traiga los últimos tres registros (por ejemplo) de una tabla en concreto, pero dependiendo del campo ID.

La tabla tiene esta estructura:

```
pages_id      data
------------------------------
1060          Juan Carlos
1062          Ana Maria
1063          Jose Eduardo
1064          Juan Camilo
1068          Mario Andres
```

La consulta SQL debería traer los *ID's* `1063`, `1064` y `1068`.

Para lograr esto, intenté con `ORDER BY` y `LIMIT`, así:

```
SELECT ft.pages_id, 
       ft.data AS titulo, 
       fb.data AS body, 
       fi.data AS imagen, 
       pg.name AS link 
FROM   field_title ft 
       JOIN field_body fb 
         ON ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id 
       JOIN field_images fi 
         ON fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
       JOIN pages pg 
         ON pg.id = pg.id 
WHERE  ( fi.created = (SELECT Min(fi2.created) 
                       FROM   field_images fi2 
                       WHERE  fi2.pages_id = ft.pages_id) ) 
ORDER  BY ft.pages_id DESC 
LIMIT  3;
```

**El problema es que esta consulta me trae el último registro (1068) repetido tres veces.**

¿Hay alguna falla en la consulta?

En [este Fiddle pueden ver la ventana de comandos SQL y hacer pruebas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ffb41/1/0).

Gracias

Comment: Para mi gusto la otra respuesta que refieres se quedó a medias, ya que se requería allí puede obtenerse combinando `GROUP_CONCAT` con `GROUP BY`. También para este caso podría servirte. Lo cierto es que para que no te repita datos tienes que agrupar de alguna manera. Usar las dos combinaciones antes mencionadas te permite traer en una sola fila valores agrupados con un separador e incluso armar estructuras complejas tipo JSON. [Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967), si observas la columna `recivers` en el último resultado, son valores de varias filas.

Comment: No hay falla, lo que ocurre es que no trae los datos que estas esperando. No es un registro repetido, el tema es que son distintos `fi.data ` por cada fila. ¿Que es lo que finalmente buscas? ¿todas las filas de los últimos 3 ft.pages_id?

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por su consejo, caballero. Traté de implementarlo pero no me trae nada, tengo un error de syntax.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho exactamente. Las últimas tres en orden descendente, es decir, los tres números más altos en `pages_id`

Comment: ¿Que versión de `mysql`estas usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que básicamente deberías buscar los últimos 3 distintos `pages_id` según esta fecha `created` por lo que bastaría con agregar este filtro a tu consulta:

```
   and ft.pages_id IN (SELECT *
                           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pages_id
                                        FROM   field_images
                                        ORDER BY created DESC
                                        LIMIT 3
                                 ) M
                       )
```

¿Por que un `select` sobre otro `select`? son las curiosidades de `Mysql` que no permite usar el `LIMIT`  en una subconsulta pero si en una subconsulta de una subconsulta.

Aquí el **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ffb41/72/0)**

Comment: Gracias Patricio por su tiempo, pero me sigue trayendo más valores de los que debería

Comment: @EMCode, claro, es lo que te comentaba antes, en tu consulta cada `pages_id` tiene varias filas una por cada imagen, ¿quieres una sola imagen por fila? ¿cual sería?

Comment: Hola, ya entendí tu respuesta, estaba omitiendo un valor en mi base de datos. Un error mío que ya resolví. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tu consulta esta bien pero el problema es que las últimas dos columnas

```
fi.data AS imagen, 
pg.name AS link
```

te retornan datos diferentes por ende se repiten los `pages_id` si quitas esas columnas y agregas un `distinct`  te retorna la consulta sin repetirse.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ft.pages_id, 
       ft.data AS titulo, 
       fb.data AS body 
FROM   field_title ft 
       JOIN field_body fb 
         ON ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id 
       JOIN field_images fi 
         ON fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
       JOIN pages pg 
         ON pg.id = pg.id 
WHERE  ( fi.created = (SELECT Min(fi2.created) 
                       FROM   field_images fi2 
                       WHERE  fi2.pages_id = ft.pages_id) ) 

ORDER  BY ft.pages_id DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

Ahora si necesitas esas columnas siempre se repetiran los `pages_id`

Comment: En principio funciona, pero no está haciendo caso a la tabla `field_images`. Acabo de editar mi pregunta con una solución que encontré, pero me surge ahora validar el valor de un campo con otro.

Answer (score -1):

Y si probas usando la funcion `TOP()`, asi solamente traes la cantidad de registros que vos queres, sin que sean repetidos

```
SELECT TOP(3)
       ft.pages_id, 
       ft.data AS titulo, 
       fb.data AS body, 
       fi.data AS imagen, 
       pg.name AS link 
FROM   field_title ft 
       JOIN field_body fb 
         ON ft.pages_id = fb.pages_id 
       JOIN field_images fi 
         ON fi.pages_id = ft.pages_id 
       JOIN pages pg 
         ON pg.id = pg.id 
WHERE  ( fi.created = (SELECT Min(fi2.created) 
                       FROM   field_images fi2 
                       WHERE  fi2.pages_id = ft.pages_id) ) 
ORDER  BY ft.pages_id DESC
```

Proba y me cuentas como te va !

Comment: TOP es una función que no existe en MySQL que es el gestor que usa el OP

Comment: Una alternativa a TOP puede ser LIMIT, pero el OP la utiliza al final de la pregunta